# How to retrieve data from Compute Shader to CPU?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

I want to retrieve data that has created by the compute shader but have no clue how it works. After researching a few forums and articles on how it should work and this is what I came up with.

**Compute Shader Code**

```
#version 430 core

layout  (local_size_x  =  100)  in;

layout(std430, binding=0) buffer Pos{
    float Position[];
};

void main(){
    Position[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = float(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);
}
```

**Program Code**

```
public float[] useProgram(int x_size, int y_size, int z_size){
        
        this.group_x_size = (int)Math.ceil(x_size/100);
        this.group_y_size = (int)Math.ceil(y_size/100);
        this.group_z_size = (int)Math.ceil(z_size/100);
        float[] data = new float[x_size];
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(x_size);
        buffer.put(data);
        int ssbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();// creates empty VBO as an object and stores it in OpenGl memory
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,buffer,GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
        GL43.glBindBufferBase(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
        
        GL20.glUseProgram(computeProgram);//start the shader program
        GL43.glDispatchCompute(group_x_size, 1, 1);
        GL43.glMemoryBarrier(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
        String values = GL43.glMapBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL43.GL_WRITE_ONLY).asFloatBuffer().toString();
        GL43.glUnmapBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
        System.out.println(values);
        
        return null;
    }
```

However this code just simply will not work the way I want it to. When I go to print out the Values it comes up null. Is there something wrong with the code or is there a better way to do it. I've looked through many forums but most of them aren't written in java.

Comment: One thing is that when you map the buffer you're passing GL_WRITE_ONLY. But you want to retrieve the values in the buffer, so you probably want GL_READ_ONLY for that.

Comment: Also, I think you want GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT instead of GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT. The barrier bits refer to operations _after_ the barrier that need to wait for shader writes prior to the barrier. glMapBuffer falls under the BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT.

Comment: @NathanReed The program still somehow returns null whenever I run it.

Comment: Next thing to try might be hooking up [debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) to see if there are any errors/warnings that might shed light on what's going wrong. See also [this question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/how-to-do-error-handling-with-opengl).

Comment: @NathanReed after I switched out GL_DYNAMIC_COPY code for GL_READ_ONLY instead of returning null the whole thing just crashed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, you don't need to change the GL_DYNAMIC_COPY (and GL_READ_ONLY is not a valid value for that anyway). But you do need to replace GL_WRITE_ONLY with GL_READ_ONLY in the glMapBuffer call.